# How to use different typefaces in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I don't want to use the default font of Android Studio, I'm writing an application so I want to use my own typefaces in my computer not what Android Studio gives to developer. How can I do that?

Comment: To be clear: You are asking to change the font of Android Studio *itself*, not the font used in the app you are writing? Then change it under Settings -> Editor -> Font

Comment: If you're talking about the font in an app you wrote-  Android Studio has nothing to do with that.  Android Studio is a fancy text editor, it doesn't provide anything.  The font in your app is determined by what the OEM of your phone provided as the default.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to change the actual font of the editor inside Android Studio, you can do so from the settings menu:

Settings > Font

[Android Studio settings menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7vXI.png)

You should be able to see all your locally installed fonts.

If you're looking to use a different font in app, you can add fonts this way:
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/fonts-in-xml

And then set them in your TextView using `android:fontFamily` attribute.